# Как сделать кнопку которая удаляет все элементы с страницы .(React JS)

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть страница где можно загрузить фото с сервера и форма с инпутами и кнопками .
Я применяю localStorage для того что бы сохранять изменения при перезагрузки страницы.
Так вот как сделать кнопку для удаления всех элементов?

```
const ChangeClickImg = (props) => {

const changeDog = useSelector((state) => state.changeReducer.dogs) 
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const deletesd = useSelector((state) => state .changeReducer.dogCleaner)
 const onChange = () => {
    dispatch(getChangePic( changeDog))
  }

  const deleteBlock = pos => {
    const changeDog = [...changeDog]
    changeDog.splice(pos,1)
   }

   localStorage.setItem('saveDog',JSON.stringify(changeDog))
   
 

  const removeItems = id => {
    deletesd(prevState => prevState.filter(el => el.id !== id))
  }
     
    return (
           
            <div>
           
            <button onClick = {() =>  onChange(changeDog)}  className = {style.ChangeButt}>Change Img</button>
            {
              changeDog.map(item => {
                  

                return (
                  <Dog key={item.id} message={item.message} status={item.status} removeItems={removeItems} deletesd={deletesd} />
                )
              })
            }

             
               <button onClick={deleteBlock}>Del</button>
         </div>
  
          )    
}
export default ChangeClickImg
  
введите сюда код
```

Comment: Каких элементов? Где пример кода, который демонстрирует Ваши попытки и неудачи?

Comment: Вот добавил код .